# Servo speed controlled by angle of analog stick

Tags: c++

This is the code I have for controlling my servo currently. It moves the servo to the angle from the analog stick input.

```
servoVal2 = analogRead(joyY1);                     
servoVal2 = map(servoVal2, 0, 1023, 0, 180);      
servo2.write(servoVal2);                          
delay(10);
```

What I want instead is for the analog value to determine the speed for the servo to move rather than the position.

Answer (score 0):

[Disclosure, I am not an expert on this topic.]

First of all you should check if your servo is capable of continuous rotation, based on your code snippet this might not be the case, because you only map the angle to a range between 0 and 180.

In case the servo can indeed rotate the full range, you will need some sort of loop which continuously sends a new target angle to the controller of the servo. Here is some pseudo code:

```
stepMillis = 100
stepAngleMaxInDegree = 30
stepAngleInDegree = stepAngleMaxInDegree / 2
lastAngleInDegree = 0

loop() {
    input = analogRead(joyY1)
    stepAngleInDegree = map(input, 0, 1023, 0, stepAngleMaxInDegree)

    while (True) {
        delay(stepMillis)
        lastAngleInDegree = (lastAngleInDegree + stepAngleInDegree) % 360
        servo2.write(lastAngleInDegree)
    }
}
```

Even in that case it is not entirely clear to me how the servo will behave on crossing the full circle, e.g. from 358° to 3°. Will it rotate 5° or -355°?

Thinking about it there might be another problem: My answer did not take into account the *actual* angular velocity of the servo. If it is fixed and the step duration is too long, it will probably not be a continuous motion, but steps and pauses.